# While True loop python

Tags: python

I'm a beginner and I would like to make a while loop in python. I have two intersecting coplanar curves and I would like to move the first curve a certain vector on the common plane until they no longer intersect. I tried something like:

```
vec = [0,0.1,0]
int = True
while True:
    move=rs.MoveObject(curve1,vec)
    int=rs.CurveCurveIntersection(curve1, curve2)
    if int = False:
        break
```

Anyone knows what am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't use `int` as a variable name, you are masking the built-in type here.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: For starters, you need `==` instead of `=`: `if int == False:` (or just `if not int:`). Beyond that and the `int` @MartijnPieters mentioned, you'll need to tell us specifically what's happening (errors? show us the traceback) and how that's different from the output you expect to see

Comment: You could simplify it to `if not rs.CurveCurveIntersection(curve1, curve2): break` and lose the `int` variable altogether.

Comment: Sure, sorry for not posting the error!

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you are using the int key word (integer type) as a variable and explicitly setting the 'int' variable to False (which is a syntax error in an if). This can mess up your system. You are also not showing what the error message is.

```
intersect = rs.CurveCurveIntersection(curve1, curve2)
if not intersect:
  break
```

Answer (score 1):

Could be simplified to

```
vec = [0, .1, 0]

while rs.CurveCurveIntersection(curve1, curve2):
    move = rs.MoveObject(curve1, vec)
```

... and I don't quite understand what `move` is.

If `rs.MoveObject()` modifies the object, you just need `rs.MoveObject(curve1, vec)`;

if it returns a modified object, you need `curve1 = rs.MoveObject(curve1, vec)` instead (and your current code would result in an endless loop).

Comment: The initial value of curve1 and curve2 may not intersect. You would need to do the first move before entering the while loop as you show it.

Comment: @sabbahillel: I believe that is a mistake in his code - he _assumes_ the curves are already intersecting and thus must be moved. If the two curves do not initially intersect, there is no reason to run the body of the while loop at all.

Comment: OK I had assumed that the test was that the curve is moved whether or not it intersects and then the checks would be done. Since we do not know what he wants, either could be true.